# Solving sum of poisson

Tags: linear-algebra, poisson-distribution

I'm trying to solve this summation but I got stuck at the last step. Hope anyone could help me with this algebra.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 10000\cdot(n-1)\cdot\frac{1.5^n\cdot e^{-1.5}}{n!}$

Comment: First $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 10000\cdot(n-1)\cdot\frac{1.5^n\cdot e^{-1.5}}{n!} = 10000\cdot e^{-1.5}\cdot\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (n-1)\cdot\frac{1.5^n}{n!}$

Comment: well I don't have trouble with this until I come across sum from 0 to infty of n-1

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=1.5$. One has
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\left(n-1\right)a^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{na^n}{n!}-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{a^n}{\left(n-1\right)!}-\left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}-1\right)$$
$$=a\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{a^{n}}{n!}-\left(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{a^n}{n!}-1\right)=1+\left(a-1\right)e^a.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 10000(n-1)\frac{1.5^ne^{-1.5}}{n!} $$ $$= 10000\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1.5^ne^{-1.5}}{(n-1)!} -10000\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1.5^ne^{-1.5}}{n!} $$ $$ =15000\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1.5^ne^{-1.5}}{n!} -10000\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1.5^ne^{-1.5}}{n!} + 10000 e^{-1.5}$$ and the two sums are obvious from the definition of a Poisson distribution.

Comment: thank s how do you get 15000?

Comment: $1.5 \times 10000$ because I changed the start from $n=1$ to $n=0$

Comment: yeah I know  that but I dunno how 1.5 is needed.could you explain a bit more please coz I couldn't see it thanks

Comment: $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1.5^ne^{-1.5}}{(n-1)!} = 1.5 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1.5^{n-1}e^{-1.5}}{(n-1)!} = 1.5 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1.5^{k}e^{-1.5}}{k!}$

Comment: I think I got it now n-1=k will solve the problem